# Is compiler able to optimize reference creation?

Tags: java, optimization

Take for example a loop like this:

```
public boolean method(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (this.object.getSomething().getSomeArray().get(i).getArray().size() > 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Each `get` method simply retrieves a private attribute. A more readable version of the same code would be:

```
public boolean method(){
    MySomeArray mySomeArray = this.object.getSomething().getSomeArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        MyArray array = mySomeArray.get(i).getArray();
        if (array.size() > 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Another version is:

```
public boolean method(){
    MySomeArray mySomeArray = this.object.getSomething().getSomeArray();
    MyArray array;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        array = mySomeArray.get(i).getArray();
        if (array.size() > 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I know that in theory compilers can optimize many things and in this case, (in my opinion) the three versions of the loop should be optimized in exactly the same machine code. 
Am I correct or there would be difference in terms of number of instructions executed in the three versions?

Comment: FWIW, the second and third versions are pretty much completely equivalent, perhaps even in terms of the generated assembly.

Comment: @BeeOnRope isn't it a potential problem a declaration inside the loop? In other words, should I always feel free to declare variables inside loop?

Comment: Yes, you should feel free. There is no such thing as "reference creation" at the site of declaration. Declaring locals themselves is free - it is only when you assign them (e.g., via new() or calling some method) has any cost (even at the bytecode level, not even considering JIT). So there is no downside to declaring the variable in the loop, and in fact it is considered good practice to declare a variable at the smallest possible scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `MySomeArray`, as well as all other classes involved in your dereference chain, are at the bottom of their respective class hierarchies, then HotSpot will have an easy time turning all those virtual function calls into "plain" (non-virtual) calls by a technique known as *monomorphic call site* optimization.

This can also happen even if the classes involved are not leaf classes. The important thing is that at each call site, only one object type ever gets dispatched on.

With the uncertainty of virtual functions out of the way, the compiler can proceed to inline all the calls, and then to perform any further optimizations, like hoisting in your case. The ultimate values retrieved from the chain of dereferencing can be bound to registers, etc.

Note that much of the above is subject to the entire code path being free of any *happens-before* relations to the actions of other threads. In practice this mostly means no `volatile` variable access and no `synchronized` blocks (within your own code as well as within all the code called from your code).

Comment: Very useful, thanks, I need to improve my knowledge about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Write a test case that uses this method and [print the generated assembly code](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2013/06/printing-generated-assembly-code-from.html) when you run it. You can then check yourself how many of the calls are inlined. I'm skeptical about the compiler being able to inline them all, but the JIT compiler can be surprising.

I would prefer the more readable version anyway, because it's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

With enough inlining, the compiler can indeed *hoist* the method calls out of the loop, very much like you did by hand in your second and third examples. The details of whether it will actually do this depend entirely on the behavior and size of the methods in question, and the sophistication of the JIT involved.

I wrote up your example and tested it with Caliper, and all the methods have equivalent timings. I didn't inspect the assembly, since that's more involved - but I'll bet they are near equivalent.

Comment: HotSpot can easily detect *monomorphic call sites* and proceed from there to inlining, hoisting, etc.

Comment: I agree that monomorphic call sites are easily detected, but for whatever reason with non-local references the assembly usually shows a re-read (from memory) of the reference, rather than a hoist, unrolling, etc. I've mostly looked at Java 6 disassembly, so may it has improved since then.

Comment: I have witnessed many times the hoisting of method calls in a for-loop condition (such as `String#length`).

Comment: As have I - my comment was about methods where the receiving reference is not a local or a parameter. I'm not saying it's a universal defect either - but I've certainly seen very simple cases fitting the above where HotSpot failed to elide the obvious reference read. No volatile or other happens-before complications present.

Comment: Yes, I'm not stupid enough to put a println in there. I guess it will just have to wait until someone dumps the assembly :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I wrote it up and tested it with Caliper, and even under Java 6 I couldn't reproduce the behavior I mentioned above. So you are right, and it seems like hotspot does fine with this scenario. I updated by answer.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that you are making assumptions that the compiler cannot make.

You know that `this.object.getSomething().getSomeArray()` does not change each time around the loop but the compiler has no way to know that. Especially since other threads may potentially be modifying those variables at the same time...

Comment: You are underestimating the powers of HotSpot... the other threads are irrelevant unless there's explicit *happens-before* ordering.